# Using constants defined in header file

Tags: java, opengl, jna

I'm trying to translate a X11/OpenGL demo into Java and I'm not sure how to use the constants OpenGL defines.  The only method I can think of is digging into the OpenGL headers and copying the constants to my program but is that the proper way to do it?  I imagine that there is no guarantee that those constants will be the same in a different environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't use this method to do what I want because I'm actually trying to get a preprocessor definition but it does answer my question.

You use the NativeLibrary class like so.

NativeLibrary library = NativeLibrary.getInstance("LIBRARY_NAME");
library.getGlobalVariableAddress("VARIABLE_NAME");

Edit: I feel like I should admit that it does not make sense to access a preprocessor definition, I ended up just copying the definitions into my program.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a library like [LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org/) it defines those constants for you and you don't have to worry about their actual values.

Comment: What drew me to JNA is the ability to potentially use opengl with no native libraries.

Comment: I missed the JNA tag. Copying the constants would be the only method as there is no way to magically get at them as C/C++ has no reflection. BTW JNA also uses a native library.